# What is the relationship between the Jenkins "Cobertura" and " Code Coverage API" Plugin?

Tags: jenkins, cobertura

https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/code-coverage-api/ mentions two different adapters for Cobertura XML, "cobertura" and "coberturaAdapter".

What is the difference between the two? Does one of them depend on the "Cobertura" plugin and the other doesn't? Which one should I use?

Through trial-and-error I have found out that this works in a Jenkinsfile when both plugins are installed:

```
publishCoverage adapters: [cobertura(coberturaReportFile: 'coverage.xml')], tag: 't'
```

Note that `coberturaReportFile` is *not* the parameter described in the pipeline syntax above. There `path` is mentioned for both adapters. I found `coberturaReportFile` when searching for the Java doc of a class that was mentioned in an error exception when I used `path`. The result is a UI which has a "Coverage Report" with source code rendering.

This seems to be influenced by the presence of the "Cobertura" plugin, because when I tried without it, I found that I had to use a different invocation:

```
publishCoverage adapters: [cobertura(path: 'coverage.xml')], tag: 't'
```

The UI was also different and (to my surprise) seemed to be like the one that I got with just "Cobertura" installed (no source code, box diagram instead of tables).

Comment: In case someone wonders: I am using `tag: ‘t’` because I want to merge two reports that are produced by different workers (https://plugins.jenkins.io/code-coverage-api/#plugin-content-merging-reports). That currently doesn't work:
my Jenkins job PR shows *two* coverage report links going to the same URL and the content seems to come from just one worker (no coverage information from second one).

Answer (score 1):

The Cobertura plugin currently [depends on](https://github.com/jenkinsci/cobertura-plugin/blob/1a964c2f8bdff7e6c940948f10fd2710abb5b777/pom.xml#L63) the Code Coverage API plugin, since [jenkinsci/cobertura-plugin#101](https://github.com/jenkinsci/cobertura-plugin/pull/101) (2018), and provides a `CoberturaReportAdapter` that [uses both](https://github.com/jenkinsci/cobertura-plugin/blob/1a964c2f8bdff7e6c940948f10fd2710abb5b777/src/main/java/hudson/plugins/cobertura/adapter/CoberturaReportAdapter.java#L43) the `cobertura` and `coberturaAdapter` descriptors. However, the Cobertura plugin is much older (first tagged in 2007); its own `cobertura` step's API can be seen [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/cobertura/).

The Code Coverage API *also* provides a `CoberturaReportAdapter` that [uses](https://github.com/jenkinsci/code-coverage-api-plugin/blob/master/plugin/src/main/java/io/jenkins/plugins/coverage/adapter/CoberturaReportAdapter.java#L43) the `cobertura` and `coberturaReportAdapter` (after 3.0.1) descriptors.

So, if you're using `publishCoverage` (from Code Coverage API), you do not need to have the Cobertura plugin installed at all (as you discovered) but you'd need to use the `cobertura` or `coberturaReportAdapter` adapter in order to handle that format. However, if you still have the Cobertura plugin installed, the `cobertura` symbol will be mistaken for the Cobertura plugin's own `cobertura` ("Publish Cobertura Coverage Report") *step*, and will fail. With *both* plugins installed, you must use the `coberturaAdapter` (Cobertura plugin) or `coberturaReportAdapter` (Code Coverage API) symbol for correct disambiguation.

Comment: Also see https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/INFRA-2012 for discussion of Jenkins' (lack of) handling for duplicate symbol issues like this.